# SQL Select Case and Average

Tags: sql, case, average

Hello I have a table with the tenure (integer, calculated in weeks) of employees in which the tenure is automatically calculated. I'm then trying to do an average tenure per week. However I want to cap the max tenure an employee can have as 20 (in weeks).

What I've go so far is this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT week,
AVG(CASE Tenure WHEN Tenure > '20' THEN '20' ELSE Tenure END) as Tenure
FROM table
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week
```

Am I on the right track? Please help me here. I've tried looking at other similar questions but no success.

Thanks in advance,

Giusepe Moreno

Comment: What is it with people comparing numbers to string literals these days?

Comment: Your right, I'm very new to SQL. I apologize.

Comment: No problem, I'm just seeing a very strong trend of this on SO recently (i.e. you're not the only one, by a long shot).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT week,
AVG(CASE WHEN Tenure > 20 THEN 20 ELSE Tenure END) 
FROM table
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week
```

Comment: I did add the 'End' statement in my actual query, I forgot to add it here.

I get this error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Use like AVG(CASE WHEN Tenure > 20 THEN 20 ELSE Tenure END) not CASE Tenure WHEN

Comment: Not working yet. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Try to copy and paste sql on answer. there is no 'not' keyword on it.

Comment: If you want to cap the average and not the Tenure, use this     CASE WHEN avg (Tenure) > 20 THEN 20 ELSE avg(Tenure) END

Comment: That works hktutluay. Now I understand what you meant. Sorry. And thank you very much.

Fred: capping the average wouldn't do it. But thanks also.